# ITextSharp works perfectly in unity editor but generates corrupt 0 byte file when app is build to windows standalone

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, itext, pdf-generation

The below code is supposed to generate a pdf and save it on the desktop with content in it which is happening fine in the unity editor but the final windows build fails to do so. It generated a pdf and saves in on desktop but the pdf is corrupt and shows 0byte size. I am unable to find the error, here is the code:

```
 public void EnglishPdf()
{

    FileStream fs = new FileStream(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop)+ "\\Loshu-Numerology.pdf", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None);
    Document doc = new Document(PageSize.A4);

    PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, fs);
    doc.Open();

    //Page0
    doc.NewPage();

    Paragraph title = new Paragraph("Loshu Grid Numerology Report");
    title.Alignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;

    Chunk nameChunk = new Chunk("Name: " + Gridvalues.instance.name_string + "\r\n");
    Chunk bday = new Chunk("Date of Birth: " + Gridvalues.instance.Date.text+ "-"+ Gridvalues.instance.Month.text+"-"+Gridvalues.instance.Year.text);
   /* iTextSharp.text.Image gridSample = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop) + "\\ScreenShot.png");
    gridSample.Alignment = Element.ALIGN_LEFT;*/
    doc.Add(title);

    doc.Add(nameChunk);
    doc.Add(bday);



    //Page-1
    doc.NewPage();
    Paragraph Title1 = new Paragraph("Missing Number Effects\r\n\r\n");
    Title1.Alignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
    Paragraph Description1 = new Paragraph("The missing Number in the Grid signifies what lessons a person has to learn in this lifetime and through proper analysis, we can help them in understanding what is required to learn and provide remedies for the same so that they can improve the difficult situations of life.The Numbers missing in your Grid are: \r\n\r\n");
    Description1.Alignment = Element.ALIGN_LEFT;
    Paragraph content1 = new Paragraph(missingdetailsFull);
    content1.Alignment = Element.ALIGN_LEFT;
    doc.Add(Title1);
    doc.Add(Description1);
    doc.Add(content1);


    //Page-2
    doc.NewPage();
    Paragraph Title2 = new Paragraph("Repeating Numbers\r\n\r\n");
    Title2.Alignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
    Paragraph Content2 = new Paragraph(repetitionDetails);
    Content2.Alignment = Element.ALIGN_LEFT;
    doc.Add(Title2);
    doc.Add(Content2);


    //Page-3
    doc.NewPage();
    Paragraph Title3 = new Paragraph("Planes\r\n");
    Paragraph ArrowStrength = new Paragraph("Arrows of Strength\r\n");
    Paragraph StrengthDetails = new Paragraph(strengthArrows);
    Title3.Alignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
    ArrowStrength.Alignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
    StrengthDetails.Alignment = Element.ALIGN_LEFT;
    doc.Add(Title3);
    doc.Add(ArrowStrength);
    doc.Add(StrengthDetails);

    Paragraph shortarrows = new Paragraph("\r\n\r\nFour Short Arrows\r\n");
    Paragraph shortArrowDetails = new Paragraph(shortArrows); 
    shortarrows.Alignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
    StrengthDetails.Alignment = Element.ALIGN_LEFT;
    doc.Add(shortarrows);
    doc.Add(shortArrowDetails);



    Paragraph weaknessarrow = new Paragraph("\r\n\r\nArrows of Weakness\r\n");
    Paragraph weakDetails = new Paragraph(weaknessArrows); 
    weaknessarrow.Alignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
    weakDetails.Alignment = Element.ALIGN_LEFT;
    doc.Add(weaknessarrow);
    doc.Add(weakDetails);

    //Page4
    doc.NewPage();
    Paragraph title4 = new Paragraph("Lucky Colors, Professions & Days");
    title4.Alignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
    Paragraph luckyd = new Paragraph("Lucky Days\r\n\r\n");
    luckyd.Alignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
    Paragraph lucky_days = new Paragraph(luckydays);
    lucky_days.Alignment = Element.ALIGN_LEFT; 
    doc.Add(title4);
    doc.Add(luckyd);
    doc.Add(lucky_days);


    Paragraph luckyc = new Paragraph("Lucky Colors\r\n\r\n");
    luckyc.Alignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
    Paragraph lucky_color = new Paragraph(colors);
    lucky_color.Alignment = Element.ALIGN_LEFT;
    doc.Add(luckyc);
    doc.Add(lucky_color);

    Paragraph lucky_P = new Paragraph("Lucky Professions\r\n\r\n");
    lucky_P.Alignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
    Paragraph luckyprof = new Paragraph(luckyProfessions);
    luckyprof.Alignment = Element.ALIGN_LEFT;
    doc.Add(lucky_P);
    doc.Add(luckyprof);


    //Page5
    doc.NewPage();
    Paragraph Title5 = new Paragraph("Avoid Professions, Colors");
    Title5.Alignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
    Paragraph avoidC = new Paragraph("Avoid Colors\r\n\r\n");
    avoidC.Alignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
    Paragraph avoidCol = new Paragraph(avoidColors);
    avoidCol.Alignment = Element.ALIGN_LEFT;
    doc.Add(Title5);
    doc.Add(avoidC);
    doc.Add(avoidCol);

    Paragraph avoidP = new Paragraph("Avoid Professions\r\n\r\n");
    avoidP.Alignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
    Paragraph avoidProf = new Paragraph(avoidProfessions);
    avoidProf.Alignment = Element.ALIGN_LEFT;
    doc.Add(avoidP);
    doc.Add(avoidProf);



    //Page6
    doc.NewPage();
    Paragraph Title6 = new Paragraph("KUA Number");
    Title6.Alignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
    Paragraph kuaN = new Paragraph("Your Kua Number is " + kua);
    kuaN.Alignment = Element.ALIGN_LEFT;
    doc.Add(Title6);
    doc.Add(kuaN);


    //Page7
    doc.NewPage();
    Paragraph Title7 = new Paragraph("PM-PY-PD");
    Title7.Alignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
    Paragraph PyearNumber = new Paragraph("Your Personal Year Number is "+ Py);
    PyearNumber.Alignment = Element.ALIGN_LEFT;
    Paragraph PmonthNumber = new Paragraph("Your Personal Month Number is "+ Pm);
    PmonthNumber.Alignment = Element.ALIGN_LEFT;
    Paragraph PdateNumber = new Paragraph("Your Personal Day Number is "+ Pd);
    PdateNumber.Alignment = Element.ALIGN_LEFT;
    doc.Add(Title7);
    doc.Add(PyearNumber);
    doc.Add(PmonthNumber);
    doc.Add(PdateNumber);


    //Page8
    doc.NewPage();
    Paragraph Title8 = new Paragraph("Vedic Power Boosters");
    Title8.Alignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
    Paragraph boosterDetails = new Paragraph(vedicBooster);
    boosterDetails.Alignment = Element.ALIGN_LEFT;
    doc.Add(Title8);
    doc.Add(boosterDetails);


    //Page9
    doc.NewPage();
    Paragraph Title9 = new Paragraph("Punchlines");
    Title9.Alignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
    Paragraph punchLine = new Paragraph(punchlines);
    punchLine.Alignment = Element.ALIGN_LEFT;
    doc.Add(Title9);
    doc.Add(punchLine);



    //Page10
    doc.NewPage();
    Paragraph Title10 = new Paragraph("Driver Characterstics");
    Title10.Alignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
    Paragraph driverChar = new Paragraph(characterstics);
    driverChar.Alignment = Element.ALIGN_LEFT;
    doc.Add(Title10);
    doc.Add(driverChar);

    doc.Close();

}
```

I followed some other topics similar to this but most of them were missing doc.Close() at the end which is not the case in my code. I have it from the beginning. How do I fix this?

The build also builds successfully without any error and everything runs fine. I am guessing there is something missing in the code. Any help would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrade to Itext7 and it will be fixed. Thanks